# PHP - Convert incoming HTTP POST into variables

Tags: php, xml, post

I'm working with a web service that is submitting an HTTP POST to a PHP page as follows:

FORM/POST PARAMETERS:
None

HEADERS:
Content-Type: text/xml

BODY:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <mogreet>
  <event>message-in</event>
  <type>command_sms</type>
   <campaign_id>12345</campaign_id>
   <shortcode>123456</shortcode>
  <msisdn>15552345678</msisdn>
  <carrier><![CDATA[T-Mobile]]></carrier>
  <carrier_id>2</carrier_id>
  <message><![CDATA[xxxx testing]]></message>
 </mogreet>
```

I need to be able to convert each of the XML elements into PHP variables so I can update a database. I've never had to work with an incoming POST with XML data before and not sure where to starT - I am familiar with processing incoming GET/POST requests but not raw xml.

Comment: can you get the xml code as string in php ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to use [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php). After that then you could use `SimpleXMLElement` as @ChristianGolihardt suggested.

Note that `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is only available if the `always_populate_raw_post_data` setting has been enabled in php.ini. Otherwise, it may be easiest to do this:

```
$postData = file_get_contents("php://input");
...
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($postData);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `SimpleXMLElement`:

http://php.net/manual/de/class.simplexmlelement.php

```
$xmlstr = $_POST['key'];
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
//work with $xml like this:
$event = $xml->mogreet->event;
```

You can see the key if you do this:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Most times, we work with this kind of api, we want to log it, because we can not see it:

```
$debugFile = 'debug.log'
file_put_contents($debugFile, print_r($_POST, true), FILE_APPEND);
```

Take also a look at the Answer from [Matt Browne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25111659/2441442), for getting Raw Input.

Answer (score 0):

This will eliminate all the SimpleXMLElement objects and return your array:

from an xml string:

```
<?php

$xml='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mogreet>
<event>message-in</event>
<type>command_sms</type>
<campaign_id>12345</campaign_id>
<shortcode>123456</shortcode>
<msisdn>15552345678</msisdn>
<carrier><![CDATA[T-Mobile]]></carrier>
<carrier_id>2</carrier_id>
<message><![CDATA[xxxx testing]]></message>
</mogreet>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$xml_array = json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1);

print_r($xml_array);

?>
```

from an xml file:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("mogreet.xml");

$xml_array = json_decode(json_encode((array) $xml), 1);

print_r($xml_array);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [event] => message-in
    [type] => command_sms
    [campaign_id] => 12345
    [shortcode] => 123456
    [msisdn] => 15552345678
    [carrier] => Array
        (
        )

    [carrier_id] => 2
    [message] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: The OP said the XML is coming from POST data, not a file.